# Why does Visual Studio 2015 require space "across all drives"?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When installing (and also when later installing updates to) Visual Studio 2015, a message appeared that indicates VS requires a certain amount of space "*across all drives*".

My C drive is my system drive, and it is a single drive with at least 2 terabytes free.

My D drive is a RAID 10 array, 3TB is size, plenty of free space.

Since I installed Visual Studio 2015 on my C drive, I see CONSTANT ACTIVITY accessing my drive D RAID array. My RAID device has LEDs for each member disk that light up when drive access is taking place.

Any time VS is running, even if it's just showing only the start screen with no projects loaded, the RAID array shows constant access activity.

The moment I close VS, the RAID array stops lighting up, which indicates no activity.

**I am really paranoid about intrusive software.** I'm beginning to wonder if VS is copying stuff from my RAID array -- it should not even be accessing any other drive but the one where I installed it!!

I would sure like to hear some comments on this from the Microsoft VIP folks here.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2012/03/07/why-visual-studio-11-requires-space-on-the-system-drive/